# PNG file or PDF file- Which offers better quality

Tags: android, png, mupdf

I have a list of thumbnail images coming from server. On clicking the thumbnail nail image, the image should be enlarged. I have a confusion with the file format(Which one to use: PDF/PNG). Can anyone suggest me which format is better

Comment: I don't even know how PDF would work but if they don't use fancy color schemes I'd consider using .gif instead since they can be made to be tiny. Otherwise .png should be fine for small images. It's what all the android icons are anyway.

Comment: PNG is a bitmap format, PDF is a richer format which may include vector data (including text). For scaling PDF is much better. Of course, if the original is pure bitmap data, that's irrelevant.

Comment: Overzealous zapping strikes again. This question has a correct answer that is not opinion based. Obviously the poster is unfamiliar with file formats and needs help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PDF**

Portable Document Format (PDF) is an open file format which makes the PDF format suitable for sharing. These files can be viewed in a professional software program or a free acrobat reader.

**PNG**

New image file format with advantages over GIF and JPEG. PNG use lossless compression of data in a wonderful way – the format compress the images so that you will not be able to detect degradation of quality. PNG files are saved with .png extension. PNG file can support both 8-bit or 24-bit colors, using a lossless compression approach.

PNG file settings that can be controlled are: 
Transparency information
File defined background color
Adobe Gamma correction

Use of a PNG file in a Web project is a good fit. However, because of the lack of support for the CMYK color space, and the fact that there can be no color separations, the PNG file is not a good fit in a print production cycle.

---

Nontheless, JPG still offers the **highest compression ratios**.
And GIF offers the ability of showing **small animations** (which you can simulate displaying a series of PNGs in sequence), even if only using a maximum of 256 colors, only one of which can be set as transparent.

Comment: Nontheless, JPG still offers the **highest compression ratios**. And GIF offers the ability of showing **small animations** (which you can simulate displaying a series of PNGs in sequence), even if only using a maximum of 256 colors, only one of which can be set as transparent.

Comment: yes you are absoultely right . but comparison is between PNG vs PDF here.

Comment: Just to add more info to your answer ;) .

Comment: Thank you Funkystein. you can edit my answer. :)